# How do I prevent AppEngine memcache flushes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

We are currently using AppEngine's memcache to store session information (session tokens) and to cache some HTML data. Our overall memcache usage is below 1 MB most of the time.

How do we prevent the cache to flush after a few minutes (this morning we had a after 40 minutes with only 25 KB). Yesterday (2013-10-15 21:30 UTC - 2013-10-15 21:45) we had flushes sometime within 2 to 7 seconds (with below 20 KB of data)?

Answer (score 4):

With the default free memcache your apps memcache data is stored along with that of other AppEngine apps, and so if the other apps cause the available memory to fill up then your data is just as likely to be expired as theirs is (see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/memcache). Therefore your application should not expect a cached value to always be available.

You can however configure your app to use Dedicated memcache (in the admin console, under Application Settings). This dedicates specific memory for your apps use only but comes at a cost of $0.12 per GB per hour.

Comment: The problem is, that dedeciated memcache is a preview feature (so no SLA etc) and that the minimum amount of dedicated memcache storage is 1 GB (ie 1051 $ a year, which is more than double the amount we are currently spending for all AppEngine usage). I would at least expect that, that the shared memcache should hold 10 MB for several hours (as it did in the past).

Comment: It is possible that your problem is related to AppEngine v1.8.6 being rolled out yesterday (see https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes). It may be that some time is required for things to settle down.

Comment: But at least on our staging server (an app where billing is currently disabled) flushes still occur in  less than 1 hour (with just 25 KB data in cache)

Comment: I have a small site/low traffic and I find that memcache tends to keep things around when there is a bit more activity.  However this varies a lot. However this morning nothing would hang around for more than a few minutes.  Right at the moment its oldest entries are over just over 2 hours.  Last week we had stuff in cache for nearly 24 hours.  I typically have between 1.5MB and a max of 8MB in cache.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to store this data persistently on datastore and use memcache to get the query result or set it if not in memcache. I have read a lot about 'forcing' memcache to perform differently than it has been designed for, but it remains the fact that you cannot never been 100% certain that you will find the data there when you ask for a get.

All the session handlers I tried provide tokens storage into a User model, [for example](https://github.com/abahgat/webapp2-user-accounts).
You can extend this model or create another one to store HTML.

Check out [here](https://github.com/abahgat/webapp2-user-accounts/blob/master/main.py) for use of `@webapp2.cached_property` also